# Ubuntu freezes abruptly. I have to switch over to one of the tty and then back to tty7 in order to unfreeze it. How can I solve the problem?

Tags: nvidia, compiz, freeze, tty

I use ubuntu 14.04 on Asus X552CL. (i3/4GB ram/1.8Ghz/1GB graphic card).
I didn't face this problem earlier. However, it started occurring frequently since this week. 
Major changes that I did this week are:
Install proprietary Nvidia graphic card. And play around wih compiz and emerald in order to install new themes.
I don't know what's causing this problem. The OS freezes abruptly and frequently- keyboard and mouse doesn't respond. I have two options then: to force shutdown by hard pressing the power button for few secs, or switch into tty mode using ctrl + alt+ f1 (any of the function keys from f1 to f6). When I switch back to gui mode using f7, the OS unfreezes. But since this is happening very frequently, I need to solve it as soon as possible.

Comment: How did you install the proprietary drivers?

Comment: @Fabby I used the "softwares & drivers". -> additional drivers-> click on Nviia drivers-> apply.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT FOLLOW ANY ADVICE TO DELETE COMPIZ!

I had the same problem after tweaking compiz.  Unfortunately I followed someone's advice to delete compiz and destroyed my installation.  The solution I found was to install Ubuntu again.  When I chose LVM to look at the layout, it wiped my drive without warning.  It is the only option that does not give a warning once you have continued after checking it.

If you originally partitioned the /home on a separate drive, I have been told you can select the same partition for /home on the new install without losing the current data and settings.  However, you may have some tweaking to do to get some apps to cooperate.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons as for why this may be happening. When it comes to your desktop there are several layers that create your desktop. Most all of the flavors or distros all start with the X window system. After that, you will have your Display Manager, and your Window Manager then you will have the final product .. For instance. You have Cinnamon.. Cinnamon doesnt use the Display managers like FXCE or LXDE and KDE. it uses MUFFIN, which is a GTK+3 engine. and it works best with the LightDM display manager, Though Linux Mint itself also has the MDM & GDM Display managers that it can also use. Each one has its own bells and whistles. Personally i find that cinnamon works best with LightDM.

As i am sure you have figured out about us LINUX types, we LOVE to customize our rigs. but we also like our consistency throughout the build.  There is a few of us out there who happen to just like them all.. and unfortunately for us we cant just make a big super os with a little of KDE Plasma, and a Lil of the Arch, and a little of debian and some of that ubuntu and some Openbox or fluxbox and a whole bunch of Awesome.. because they dont all work together.. what im getting at is that, when you start mixxing some of the base components of one display manager with another and so forth.. things start to fall apart. If your enjoying the GDK stylings. then steer clear of things that venture into KDE or LXQT or XFCE.. thats when your UI starts to do the glitching and falling apart.

also sometimes you might just need to restart your DM, simple... <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> . is one way.. or you might need to restart your Xserver. that is done with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>  ...

Hope that helps a little bit. There are plenty of good comparison articles around for the DIfferences between KDE and XFCE or LX and Openbox etc.. a good sight to look at for help in finding alternatives is alternativeto.net